# SQL update Statement not changing record

Tags: java, sql, syntax

I have an sql update statement but I an't figure out why it doesn't update my records, it just does nothing, is there anything wrong with the syntax?

```
    private static final String strUpdatePerson =
        "UPDATE APP.PERSON " +
        "SET FIRSTNAME = ?, " +
        "    LASTNAME = ?, " +
        "    ADDRESS = ?, " +
        "    PHONE = ?, " +
        "    EMAIL = ?, " +   
        "    INFO = ? " +
        "WHERE ID = ?";
```

It's very confusing because there is no error given, it performs the update but changes nothing in the database.

Edit:

Here's the query being executed:

```
    stmtUpdateExistingRecord = dbConnection.prepareStatement(strUpdateCustomer);


    stmtUpdateExistingRecord.clearParameters();
        stmtUpdateExistingRecord.setString(1, record.firstName.toUpperCase());
        stmtUpdateExistingRecord.setString(2, record.lastName.toUpperCase());
        stmtUpdateExistingRecord.setString(3, record.Address);
        stmtUpdateExistingRecord.setString(4, record.phoneNumber);
        stmtUpdateExistingRecord.setString(5, record.email);
        stmtUpdateExistingRecord.setString(6, record.info);
        stmtUpdateExistingRecord.setInt(7, record.getID());
        stmtUpdateExistingRecord.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: How do you use that statement? Please, supply community a peace of code that use the statement.

Comment: Maybe the transaction is rolled back rather than committed. Show us the code.

Comment: Are you sure you are binding the correct ID value (i.e. does it exist in the database)?

Comment: My code is pretty much a copy of the tutorial shown here:http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javadb/ so it's very strange that it doesn't work.

Comment: Turns out my problem was nothing to do with the sql query but a problem higher up that caused the id to be 0. Stupid Mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You should either call `dbConnection.setAutoCommit(true);` *before* the `executeUpdate()` or `dbConnection.commit();` *after* the `executeUpdate()`

If `dbConnection.getAutoCommit()` returns true, then you're experiencing a different error. Are you sure it's not throwing an `Exception`?

Comment: Sorry I pieced the code together for the question. Everything is fine with dbconnection because the other queries work fine. And yes there are no exceptions thrown it's very strange. Most of the time it updates and does nothing but sometimes it will give an sql timeout error

Comment: Sounds like your DB might be acting weirdly. Did you try running the query on the DB directly using a utility?